# Let polkit/pkexec use another application to ask for my password

Tags: gnupg, password-store, pkexec

I would like pkexec (polkit) to always ask for my password through a particular application and not through the default one. What I need is the equivalent of `sudo --askpass`.

I would like that so that polkit always uses my gnupg agent and password store.